# If $X$ is distributed $\mathcal{N}\sim(\mu,1)$ then what is the PDF of $X^2$?

Tags: probability, self-learning, density-function

If $X$ is distributed $\mathcal{N}\sim(\mu,1)$ then what is the distribution of $X^2$?
My try:
\begin{align*}
    P(X^2<x)\\ 
    P(-\sqrt{x}<X<\sqrt{x})\\
    \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} f(x) \,dx 
\end{align*}
Then:
\begin{align*}
    f_{X^{2}}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\sqrt{-x}}^{\sqrt{x}} f(x) \,dx\\
    =f_X(\sqrt{x})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+f_X(-\sqrt{x})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\\
    =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x}} e^{\frac{-(\sqrt{x}-\mu)^2}{2}}
\end{align*}
How should I continue?

Comment: I think you mean $-\sqrt{x}$ not $\sqrt{-x}$.

Comment: Hi, this should help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192807/pdf-of-the-square-of-a-standard-normal-random-variable

Comment: Your substitution into the Gaussian pdf in the last line looks incorrect.

Comment: Cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/499079/119261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X^2$ is a member of the family of [noncentral chi-squared distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).  There are a few problems with your calculations as others have pointed out.  Notably, you should not use the same variable to represent both the limits of integration and the variable of integration.  You should write instead
$$\begin{align}
f_{X^2}(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} \int_{t=-\sqrt{x}}^\sqrt{x} f_X(t) \, dt \\
&= \frac{f_X(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{f_X(-\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi x}} \left( e^{-(\sqrt{x}-\mu)^2/2} + e^{-(\sqrt{x} + \mu)^2/2} \right).
\end{align}$$
Your main computational error is in assuming that $f_X(\sqrt{x}) = f_X(-\sqrt{x})$.  This is not true unless $\mu = 0$.

We can stop here, or we can perform additional algebraic manipulations:  note
$$(\sqrt{x} \pm \mu)^2 = x \pm 2\mu \sqrt{x} + \mu^2,$$ therefore
$$e^{-(\sqrt{x} - \mu)^2/2} + e^{-(\sqrt{x} + \mu)^2/2} = e^{-x/2} e^{\mu \sqrt{x}} e^{-\mu^2/2} + e^{-x/2} e^{-\mu \sqrt{x}} e^{-\mu^2/2} = e^{-(x + \mu^2)/2} (e^{\mu \sqrt{x}} + e^{-\mu \sqrt{x}}).$$  Since $e^z + e^{-z} = 2 \cosh z$, we can write $$f_{X^2}(x) = \frac{e^{-(x+\mu^2)/2} \cosh (\mu \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}, \quad x \ge 0.$$

This density corresponds to a noncentral chi-squared distribution with $1$ degree of freedom and noncentrality parameter $\mu^2$.

Comment: From this result can I derive the density function of the sum of several normal distributed random variables with different mean and variance 1?